# Facing error in display table in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

My controller function is

```
public function listAction()
 {
       $params = array('host'       =>'localhost',
                        'username'  =>'root',
                        'password'  =>'',
                        'dbname'    =>'zend'
                         );
        $DB = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params);
        $DB->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY user_name ASC";
        $result = $DB->fetchAssoc($sql);
        echo count($result);
        $this->view->assign('title','Member List');
        $this->view->assign('description','Below, our members:');
        $this->view->assign('datas',$result);
 }
```

and phtml file is fetching mysql table by

```
<?php 
$datas = $this->datas;
    for($i = 1; $i<= count($datas);$i++)
    { echo $datas[$i]['id'];
  echo $datas[$i]['user_name'];
  echo $datas[$i]['first_name'];  
  echo $datas[$i]['last_name'];
       } ?>
```

It shows error in of undefined offset=1, if i start for loop from 2 it is ok and shows one less row form mysql table.

Please help, i am not getting where the mistake

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 1):

Because $datas doesn't have array index of 1. Replace your phtml file with the following code. Hope that will help.

```
<?php
$datas = $this->datas;
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    echo $data['id'];
    echo $data['user_name'];
    echo $data['first_name'];
   echo $data['last_name'];
 }
?>
```